# Bootstrap Vue Aria Attributes not working in Firefox

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am adding a BootstrapVue b-pagination component in my Vue 2 app and having issues with the aria attributes. I'm using the page-click event to check the aria-attributes of the clicked on item.  On Chrome, I am able to retrieve the attribute via the event object. On Firefox, these attributes are undefined.

template

```
        <b-pagination
          v-model="currentPage"
          :total-rows="total"
          :per-page="15"
          first-text="First"
          prev-text="Prev"
          next-text="Next"
          last-text="Last"
          v-on:page-click="pageClicked"
        ></b-pagination>
```

JS

```
      pageClicked(e){
          // these are defined properly on Chrome, but undefined in Firefox
          console.log(e.target.ariaLabel, e.target.ariaPosInSet ) 
      },
```

Comment: Based on this link (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/ariaPosInSet) and this one (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/ariaLabel), you cannot use those attributes in Firefox (Not compatible). I'm looking for other options, but would you please tell me why you need those attributes?  I want to know the use case to better find a solution.

Comment: Also, I think you should add the `JavaScript` tag to your question.